# Ansible Firewalld Module Not Found

Tags: python, linux, ansible

Environment Information:

```
CentOS Stream release 8
Python 3.8.12
ansible [core 2.12.2]
  config file = /ansible/ansible-myprojects-rhel8/ansible.cfg
  configured module search path = ['/home/ansible/.ansible/plugins/modules', '/usr/share/ansible/plugins/modules']
  ansible python module location = /usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/ansible
  ansible collection location = /home/ansible/.ansible/collections:/usr/share/ansible/collections
  executable location = /usr/bin/ansible
  python version = 3.8.12 (default, Sep 21 2021, 00:10:52) [GCC 8.5.0 20210514 (Red Hat 8.5.0-3)]
  jinja version = 2.10.3
  libyaml = True
```

I'm trying to open http port on firewall for worker node. My playbook is below:

```
---
- name: enable web server
  hosts: target1
  tasks:
    - name: install stuff
      yum:
        name:
          - httpd
          - firewalld

    - name: create a welcome page
      copy:
        content: "welcome to the webserver \n"
        dest: /var/www/html/index.html

    - name: enable webserver
      service:
        name: httpd
        state: started
        enabled: true

    - name: enable firewall
      service:
        name: firewalld
        state: started
        enabled: true

    - name: open service in firewall
      firewalld:
        service: httpd
        permanent: true
        state: enabled
        immediate: yes
```

When I execute the playbook, it gives error:

ERROR! couldn't resolve module/action 'firewalld'. This often indicates a misspelling, missing collection, or incorrect module path.

```
The error appears to be in '/ansible/ansible-myprojects-rhel8/exercise53_4.yaml': line 28, column 7, but may
be elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.

The offending line appears to be:


    - name: open service in firewall
      ^ here
```

Than I try to look at the documentation from ansible controller server. Than below error occured:

```
[WARNING]: module firewalld not found in: /home/ansible/.ansible/plugins/modules:/usr/share/ansible/plugins/modules:/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/ansible/modules
```

I dont understand if the module is missing or sth. It passes the install stuff task which should install firewalld (or pass if it is installed but there is no log in for that. It justs skips to task open service in firewall and gives error).

Verbose output:

```
ansible-playbook [core 2.12.2]
  config file = /ansible/ansible-myprojects-rhel8/ansible.cfg
  configured module search path = ['/home/ansible/.ansible/plugins/modules', '/usr/share/ansible/plugins/modules']
  ansible python module location = /usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/ansible
  ansible collection location = /home/ansible/.ansible/collections:/usr/share/ansible/collections
  executable location = /usr/bin/ansible-playbook
  python version = 3.8.12 (default, Sep 21 2021, 00:10:52) [GCC 8.5.0 20210514 (Red Hat 8.5.0-3)]
  jinja version = 2.10.3
  libyaml = True
Using /ansible/ansible-myprojects-rhel8/ansible.cfg as config file
redirecting (type: modules) ansible.builtin.firewalld to ansible.posix.firewalld
ERROR! couldn't resolve module/action 'firewalld'. This often indicates a misspelling, missing collection, or incorrect module path.

The error appears to be in '/ansible/ansible-myprojects-rhel8/exercise53_4.yaml': line 28, column 7, but may
be elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.

The offending line appears to be:


    - name: open service in firewall
      ^ here
```

Comment: Under CentOS Linux release 8.4.2105 the firewalld module is at `/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ansible/modules/system/firewalld.py`

Comment: @MarcoBaldelli I searched for firewalld.py but it is not in ansible directory. Its in: `/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/firewall/server/firewalld.py` but it's not related to ansible.

Comment: Actually it may be related but ansible cant use that firewalld.py in above directory. I don't understand why. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I read a post about the collection that contains the firewalld module is not installed on my controller node and firewalld is in ansible.posix collection.

So I run the command below with ansible user:

```
ansible-galaxy collection install ansible.posix
```

After that the problem is solved but I don't understand why the collection is not installed to my controller node when I first install ansible (with yum). If anybody has an idea about that, please share.

Reference: http://www.freekb.net/Article?id=2991

Comment: Your are probably using the package "ansible-core", which has no included collections. You should install "ansible community" instead if you don't want to install every package manually. See [here](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/release_and_maintenance.html) for more information